# Google Analytics POST request works fine in REST Client, but not using Python Requests

Tags: python, post, google-analytics, python-requests

I'm trying to send an event to Google Analytics using a Python script.

When I try to send the event using the Google Analyics "Hit Builder", it works fine.  When I try to do the same thing with a simple POST request using the VSCode REST Client, it also works fine.  But, for reasons I can't understand, making the exact same POST request with the Python Requests library doesn't work.

Here's what I want to do.  This request works perfectly using the VSCode REST Client:

```
###
# @name analytics_post

POST www.google-analytics.com/collect
?v=1
&t=event
&tid=UA-XXXXXX-Y
&cid=Client%20ID%20Goes%20Here
&ec=Event%20Category%20Goes%20Here
&ea=Event%20Action%20Goes%20Here
&el=Event%20Label%20Goes%20Here
&ev=123
```

When I make that request, the event shows up right away in Google Analytics - great!  But when I try to do the *exact same thing* in Python with Requests, it fails:

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import urlencode, quote

params = {}

params["v"] = 1                             # Version
params["t"] = "event"                       # Event hit type
params["tid"] = "UA-XXXXXX-YY"              # Tracking ID
params["cid"] = "Client ID Goes Here"       # Anonymous Client ID
params["ec"] = "Event Category Goes Here"   # Event Category
params["ea"] = "Event Action Goes Here"     # Event Action
params["el"] = "Event Label Goes Here"      # Event label
params["ev"] = 123

url = 'https://www.google-analytics.com/collect'

query = urlencode(params, quote_via=quote)

response = requests.post(url=url, params=query)
```

After running this, I get a 200 Response object and everything looks fine.  The response even has a `url` object, which is exactly the same as the URL I formatted for the REST client request... so there aren't any issues with the way the URL is formatted.  But the data doesn't appear in Google Analytics.

Just to be sure, I tried the same code but leaving out the `quote_via=quote` parameter, so that it would default to `quote_plus`, meaning that spaces would be rendered as `+` characters rather than `%20`.  I also tried doing `data=query` instead of `params=query` in the POST request (last line).  Neither of these worked.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you don't need to urlencode if using requests

Comment: I get the same behvaiour  if I omit the urlencode line

Comment: are you sure you need the 'params' kwarg and not 'data'? i havent messed with google analytics so just asking.

Comment: I've seen differing answers on whether I should use  `params` or `data`...  Anyway I tried both and got the same behaviour.

Comment: what headers does the vs thing use? GA may not like the default python ones

Comment: REST Client uses `"User-Agent": "vscode-restclient"`.  I tried just using `{"User-Agent": ""}` as the headers per another post, and that worked.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, this was an issue with the default headers used by `requests`.  The solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62308020/post-to-google-analytics-works-from-node-fails-from-python-why?rq=1) worked for me.  I just had to also add `{"User-Agent": ""}` as the set of headers for the POST request.

This worked for me:

```
import requests

params = {}

params["v"] = 1                             # Version
params["t"] = "event"                       # Event hit type
params["tid"] = "UA-XXXXXX-YY"              # Tracking ID
params["cid"] = "Client ID Goes Here"       # Anonymous Client ID
params["ec"] = "Event Category Goes Here"   # Event Category
params["ea"] = "Event Action Goes Here"     # Event Action
params["el"] = "Event Label Goes Here"      # Event label
params["ev"] = 123

url = 'https://www.google-analytics.com/collect'

headers= {"User-Agent": ""}

response = requests.post(url=url, params=params, headers=headers)
```